# Sent an support e-mail through gmail

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I already implement the sent the e-mail support through gmail, and everything is fine. But this code seems odd, because for example the customer requested to the programmer to make an e-mail support through gmail, and when it is done, programmer give the source code to the customer along with the program. When customer open it up (the source code), the customer will know the e-mail that used to make the e-mail support along with the password. How can I prevent that? Any good solution to make the e-mail support without reveal the e-mail password in the source code?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public void SendRecoverCredentials(string _to)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient _smtp = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage _message = new MailMessage();

            _message.From = new MailAddress("credentialhelper@gmail.com", "Credential Helper - Support -");
            _message.To.Add(new MailAddress(_to, "To whom it may concern"));
            _message.Subject = "Credentials Recover";
            _message.Body = "Dear to whom it may concern" +
                "\n\n\nBelow are your credentials info:" + "\n\n\n\n" + "Please copy the Password and paste it to the program where the Old Password field is." + "\n\n\n\n" + "Username: " + UserInformation.Name + "\nPassword: " + UserInformation.Password +
                "\n\n\n\nTo avoid for future messages being moved to the spam or junk folder, please add credentialhelper@gmail.com to be your contact list." +
                "\n\n\n*** This is an automatically computer generated e-mail, please do not reply to this message ***";

            _smtp.Port = 587;
            _smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            _smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            _smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("support's e-mail address", "support's e-mail password");

            _smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            _smtp.Send(_message);

            ShowMessageBox("Your message has been successfully sent.", "Success", 2);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessageBox("Message : " + ex + "\n\nEither your e-mail or password incorrect. (Are you using Gmail account?)", "Error", 1);
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Set up a service that your application can talk to that will actually do the sending, or else allow the user to configure it with their own e-mail address.  Or even use OAuth for that purpose.  You probably don't want to use Gmail for this anyway, because they have rather restrictive limits on how much e-mail you can send through automated services.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be sending people passwords anyway.  You should have a one-way hash of their passwords that even you cannot decrypt.

Comment: Or compile the code for sending the e-mail in a DLL and send that over to the user as external DLL.

Comment: @spike So they can trivially decompile the DLL and recover it?  That's awful advice.

Comment: you are right - but it's not that trivial for everyone @emodendroket

Comment: @spike Does it matter?  It only takes one person who knows how to do it to be compromised.

Comment: @emodendroket: Thank you for your interest in this question and your answer. To make it simple on what you said (from what I am understand). First: I have to store the support's e-mail password into the database, hash that and retrieve that (only the computer will understand that), and after that set it into the support's e-mail password?

Comment: @spike: So, you mean I have to make DLL file for store any support's email address and password? And use the DLL file into the program? I did not know on how to make a DLL file, even though there would be any simpler advice to achieve this matter instead of creating DLL file and use it. Anyway, thank you for your interest in this question and your answer.

Comment: @Yunnan No, your code has multiple issues.  I'll post an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, there is no way to do exactly what you're asking.  You cannot send the client your credentials and have them be secure.  Compiling them into a DLL will stop only the least technically-savvy potential attackers.

There are a couple ways you could achieve your goal, though:

1. Have the client provide their own e-mail username and password and send through those.  This is probably the easiest because it doesn't require much set-up.
2. Use OAuth.  This is essentially the same as option 1, except instead of having them provide the password you'll have them click "give access" on a Google page or whatever.  Probably not the way to go.
3. Create a Web service you control that has the credentials stored, then have your application contact that Web service.  Your Web service can ensure it's a valid request from your app and then send the e-mail for you.  While this is the nicest solution, probably, it also needs the most work.

In addition, although it's not directly related to your question, this code is a serious problem:

`"Username: " + UserInformation.Name + "\nPassword: " + UserInformation.Password`

First of all, you shouldn't even be able to decrypt anyone's password.  You should be using a one-way hash.  There are lots of essays talking about why this is so and I won't repeat them here.  Anyway, it's a bad idea.  Additionally, sending sensitive information over e-mail is not ideal either.

Comment: ooh, you mean the `UserInformation.Password`, it is return `string` and also it retrieve the password from the database that already been hashed, so the text that will be visible on the user e-mail address will be hashed password, not the actual password. After user received that, user have to copy the hashed password from the e-mail that already been received and put it into `Old Password` textbox, and user need to fill the `New Password` textbox then when user click verify . . .

Comment: . . .the program will check if the hashed password that have been put into `Old Password`  is match with the user's username and password, if yes then the user's password will replaced by the `New Password` (and of course it will be hashed before store it into the database), then user will not be able to login anymore using the user's old password. Basically, it is like recover password and set a new one. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @Yunnan An expiring token is probably better.

Comment: Thank you, will try the third solution or first solution.